# How to iterate grouped objects in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, plotly-python

I have  DataFrame called **df_grouped** grouped by the "Chr" column as shown below.

```
   Index Trait Chr  p_adj     ind
422 94  C10.1   1   21.660747   0
470 140 C10.1   1   10.859806   1
471 141 C10.1   1   24.434861   2
472 142 C10.1   1   10.962972   3
473 143 C10.1   1   32.396856   4
... ... ... ... ... ...
1710    15  Pro 22  47.523313   5458
1711    16  Pro 22  48.683401   5459
1713    18  Pro 22  49.804377   5460
1715    20  Pro 22  7.311224    5461
1704    9   Pro 22  15.566230   5462
```

*Now I want to loop through the grouped object and return a DataFrame called **'group'** which contains all the datasets from  Chr 1 to Chr 22. unfortunately, **"group"** is only returning only Chr 22. How can I solve this problem? *

```
x_labels = []
x_labels_pos = []
groupin = []

for num, (name, group) in enumerate(df_grouped):
    #fig = px.scatter(group, x='ind', y='p_adj', color="Chr")
    x_labels.append(name)
    x_labels_pos.append((group['ind'].iloc[-1] - (group['ind'].iloc[-1] - group['ind'].iloc[0])/2))
    groupin.append(group)
```

Comment: Are you sure `df_grouped` is a `pandas.GroupBy` object and not just a `DataFrame`? Have you tried `for num, (name, group) in enumerate(df_grouped.groupby('Chr')): ...`

Comment: Yes, df_gouped is Pandas groupby object. Here is how created the object. df_grouped = GWASummaryStatisticsDF_copy.groupby('Chr')

Comment: @ChrisA , This is the snipet of what I am getting:  Index Trait Chr p_adj ind
1718 23 Pro 22 23.194227 5431
1719 24 Pro 22 46.339799 5432
1720 25 Pro 22 18.042536 5433
1721 26 Pro 22 15.503762 5434
1724 29 Pro 22 31.701802 5435
1723 28 Pro 22 37.848937 5436
1725 30 Pro 22 7.351445 5437
1726 31 Pro 22 58.670399 5438
1717 22 Pro 22 29.463063 5439

Comment: What is it that your ultimately trying to do? What's the plot you're hoping to create?

Comment: @ChrisA , I want to use **group** dataframe to generate a manhattan plot using plotly. This I suspect would be as easy as ploting Scatter plot with x= "ind" or "Chr" and y="p_adj". With my current code, I can only plot for Chr 22 yet there are "Chr" 1 to 22